# Significance of ":" in url in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning angular js , and I found this in some tutorial while explaining routing.

```
module.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
 when('/users/', {templateUrl: 'template.tpl.html', controller: myCtrl}).            
 when('/users/:userId', {templateUrl: 'template.tpl.html', controller: myCtrl})
```

}]);

What is this **:userId** in the link ? what i know is suppose we have a folder template in that if we have anotherfile user we will put the link as "template/user" , I also know this userID will be used in routerParams as a parameter for route's controller but what exactly is the meaning of : in the link above ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular, but a short google gave [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) as the first result, where it's explained: _"path can contain named groups starting with a colon: e.g. :name. All characters up to the next slash are matched and stored in $routeParams under the given name when the route matches."_

Answer (score 1):

This represent a parameter
In this case the parameter is `userID` thus those urls

> domain.com/users/0
>
> domain.com/users/1
>
> domain.com/users/2

will call the same route with `userID` 0, 1 and 2

Comment: This is how it's works : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Answer (score 0):

**It is RouteParamater**

let user have name and id

For example you have list of names of users in one page and when you click
a user it takes to another page which shows users detail.So to let the detail page know about the clicked user you must send some identification maybe in this case userid.

Example

```
<a href="#/users/{{user.id}}">{{user.name}}</a>
```

And access it via routparams

```
//Inject routeparams
var userId = routeparams.userId //user Id is defined in your route configuration
```

Comment: You can pass data without the parameters, it can be use only for display purpose

Answer (score 0):

**:userId** repesents the dynamic part of url. The value can be anything. 
It is generally used for id as you can see.  Used for creating dynamic routes.
Other frameworks like nodejs, in php  also uses this technique.